# User name in the title bar

Tags: bug, android-app

I see user name in the title when it shouldn't be showed.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Select any site on the left panel
2. Tap on the title and select users
3. Select any user (e.g. Shog9)

   > [image]
4. Select any site where user has activity

   > [image]
5. Select any site on the left panel

   > [image]
6. User name doesn't disappear from the title

   > [image]

---

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: Nexus 10
- OS Version: 5.1.1 (2640980)

Comment: No-repro on my phone. Possibly because its screen is too small to show a persistent left bar.

Comment: @JanDvorak You need a tablet. On my phone I also can't reproduce it.